# Support for R forecast in Renjin

Tags: java, r, forecasting, renjin

Have anyone managed to use R Forecast package in Renjin?
There currently seems to be some problem with the build when looking at the Renjin website

Comment: According to their [build history](http://packages.renjin.org/package/org.renjin.cran/forecast/6.0) it's never worked and they are still working on it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues blocking the use of the forecast package. I've added everything to the tracker so you can track progress.

[Issue #117](https://github.com/bedatadriven/renjin/issues/117): Dependency Rcpp uses reference classes, which are not yet working in
Renjin.

We're working on getting all the kinks worked out of S4/refClasses over the next two weeks and once this issue is resolved, you will be able to at least load the package in Renjin and use at least some of the functionality.

The remaining problems (as far as I'm aware) relate to native C/C++ sources. Most of the forecast package is in pure R, but there are a few sources written in C/C++:

[Issue #116](https://github.com/bedatadriven/renjin/issues/118): .Call() interface implementation. The forecast package has some C code which uses the .Call interface rather than the .C() interface, which Renjin supports. This is also high on our list.

[Issue #119](https://github.com/bedatadriven/renjin/issues/119): C++ code translation.

It would also be possible to fork the forecast package and rip out the Rcpp dependency to get things working faster: take a look at the [docs](http://docs.renjin.org/en/latest/writing-renjin-extensions.html) on writing Renjin packages.

Comment: Any progress on this issue and C++ support in Renjin? I am also interested in running the forecast package there. I was trying to find some working fork without those dependencies, since this seems to be quite common need but did not succeed.